# Creating Custom Plugin in Ionic2 and Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am trying to make a small custom alert plugin in Ionic 2 which says 'Hello' and can be called from my .ts file. However, I am unable to find any good resource in the web to guide me with the plugin creation process. Can someone tell how to proceed with this?

Comment: did you read the official cordova documentation https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/ 
it looks detailed enough

Answer (score 1):

First take a look at the Cordova Plugin Development Guide:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html

It might also help if you take a look at some of the existing plugins, eg the Geolocation plugin:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

When you have a working Cordova plugin you can make a Ionic Native wrapper for your plugin:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md